# Paint event delegate not invoked when refresh() method is called

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, paint

```
class MainWindow : Form
{
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Handlers
            Paint += new PaintEventHandler(MainWindow_Paint);
            MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(MainWindow_MouseClick);
        }
void MainWindow_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var p = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            m_ListOfFigures.ToArray()[0].addPoint(ref p);
            Refresh();
        }
void MainWindow_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        }
```

I have no idea why my method, registered for wm_paint, not called?
Can you point to my mistake?

Comment: How did you know that `MainWindow_Paint` was not called? (I mean I don't see much code in that method)

Comment: @KingKing breakpoint + debbuger

Comment: Why did I make it work? The code should work and I tested it.

Comment: @KingKing you mean that my subscribe method for paint event is invoked every time mouse clicked on the form?

Comment: yes, of course I just kept the line `Refresh()` in the MouseClick event handler, other code is not involved (in that handler) here.

Comment: @KingKing but it is not working in my code, the reason for my question is to figure out that is the problem.

Comment: unless you have some `overriden code in a OnPaint` somewhere, that `overriden code` removed the `base.OnPaint` and that's why `Paint` is not raised. Otherwise, I can't think that would be able to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did *should* have worked, but Microsoft say you should override `OnPaint()` rather than subscribing to the `Paint` event, to paint a user control.

As it says in the documentation for [`Control.Paint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx):

*`When creating a new custom control or an inherited control with a different visual appearance, you must provide code to render the control by overriding the OnPaint method.`*

See here for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cksxshce.aspx

But do note that doesn't really apply to Form classes (such as the one you're using), which are not User Controls or Custom Controls! Nevertheless, it's still more usual to override OnPaint() to paint the control itself.)

You should try adding the following to your form:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) 
{
     // Call the OnPaint method of the base class.
     base.OnPaint(e);

     // Now draw stuff using e.Graphics
}
```

The `Paint` event is not really intended for the user control or form itself to use. Instead, it is for when you want to be notified when a control *within* the containing control is being repainted.

**Note** However, having said that, it should still have worked using the `Paint` event... but Microsoft say that you should override `OnPaint()` to do your painting (perhaps because of issues such as the one you had).

Comment: Yes, that is it. I spent almost half of my day sorting out this issue. But haven`t found any good references in MSDN. Thank you!

Comment: @spin_eight Did you try this, and it actually fixed it? I'm not sure why it wouldn't have worked before, but it's good if it works now. :)